# Segmentation fault in bucket sort + insertion sort algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'd like to know why this algorithm I implemented for bucket sort is getting Segmentation fault as a result. It seems everything in the implementation is working nicely but there's probably some variable n that should be n+1 or whatever; I'm experiencing some difficulty figuring this one out.

I'm implementing it according to what was described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geVyIsFpxUs).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertion(int * array, int n){
    // insertion sort
    int i = 1, j = 0, temp;
    while(i < n){
        j = i;
        while(j > 0 && array[j-1] > array[j]){
            temp = array[j-1];
            array[j-1] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            --j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

void bucket(int * array, int n){
    int max,i,j,k,size, div, pos;
    int ** buckets, *bucket_position;

    //Find maximum value in array
    max = array[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) if( max < array[i] ) max = array[i];

    //Determine amount of buckets and creates them
    size = max / n;
    buckets = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * size);
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        buckets[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max);
    }
    bucket_position = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for(i=0;i<size;++i) bucket_position[i] = 0;

    //Copy array values into the buckets
    div = (max+1) / size;
    if( (max+1) % size ) ++div;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        pos = array[i] / div;
        buckets[pos][bucket_position[pos]] = array[i];
        ++bucket_position[pos];
    }

    //Take values out of the buckets into the array
    k = 0;  
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        for(j=0;j<=bucket_position[i];++j){
            array[k] = buckets[i][j];
            ++k;
        }
    }

    //Do insertion sort over the array
    insertion(array,n);
}

int main(){
    int array[5] = {24354,95023,439052,934851};
    int n = 5;
    bucket(array,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output is Segmentation fault instead of the sorted array.

Comment: Debugger..............

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804868b in bucket (array=0xbffff1a8, n=5) at test.c:41
41   buckets[pos][bucket_position[pos]] = array[i];
(gdb)

Comment: Since this happens in a loop where `i <= 0 < n`, you should look at `pos`, which propbably is out of bounds. (You can do this in gdb with `print pos` or just  `p pos`.)

Comment: @Ruan thanks for the debugging.  You should breakpoint on that line and check the valies of the indices 'pos' and 'i'.

Comment: (gdb) print pos
$1 = 4059
(gdb) print i
$2 = 0

Comment: You create 186970 buckets, each with the capacity to hold 934851 integers, all that to sort an array of size 5. Bit of an overkill, don't you think? `:)`

Comment: (gdb) print pos
$3 = 4059
(gdb) print i
$4 = 0
(gdb) print max
$5 = 934851
(gdb) print size
$6 = 186970

Comment: 934851 > 4059  and 186970  > 4059. What is happening here?

Comment: M Oehm Yes I guess this is asking for a different approach. But still I can't see why it's not working

Comment: (An array of a small size such as 5 should be passed to insertion sort directly. Insertion sort is inefficient for lagre sizes, but performs well for small arrays of maybe 10 to 15 elelemnts. Therefore, you should not create `n` buckets for an array of ´n` elements. If you assume a uniform distribution, create fewer than `n` bckets, maybe `n / 10`. You should also take into account the minimum value, so that the array `{999, 1000, 1001}` won't create 100 buckets for nothing. And you'll probably want to insertion-sort the buckets individually before merging.)

Comment: You request so much memory that not all requests can be satisfied. Check whether your `malloc`s return `NULL` and you'll see that that's what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort an array with `n == 5` elements, whose maximum vlaue is:

```
max == 934851
```

Then you calculate the nuber of buckets:

```
size = max / n == 186970
```

Now you try to allocate memory for 186970 buckets, each with a capacity to hold 934851 elements:

```
buckets = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * size);

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    buckets[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max);
}
```

That's roughly 651 Gigabytes. With so many large allocations, it is likely that the system can't provide more memory. You should therefore check whether the pointers returned from `malloc` are `NULL`. And that's what happens: Your array indices are legal, but the dynamically allocated arrays are `NULL`.

Of course you don't need that much memory to sort five elements. For such a small array, you shouldn't need to use buckets at all; use insertion sort straight away.

For larger arrays, base the number of buckets on the number of elements, not on the maximum value. In the worst case, all elements go into one bucket, which will then have `n` elements. So you don't need `max` to determine the size here, either.

You should, however, use `max` and `min`, which your program doesn't have, to calculate the bucket index:

```
index = (a[i] - min) * nbuckets / (max + 1 - min)
```

Be aware of possible arithmetic overflow here. (The `+ 1` ensures that the maximum element doesn't get the invalid index `n`.)

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
k = 0;  
for(i=0;i<size;++i){
    for(j=0;j<=bucket_position[i];++j){
        array[k] = buckets[i][j];
        ++k;
    }
}
```

is a problem.

You'll increment `k` a lot of times and thereby write outside `array`. Remember that the valid range for `k` is only 0 to 4.

Instead of

```
for(j=0;j<=bucket_position[i];++j){
        ^^^^
```

maybe you want

```
for(j=0;j<bucket_position[i];++j){
        ^^^
```

i.e. `<` instead of `<=` so that you don't increment `k` in every loop.

Comment: @Ruan - Well, for me it doesn't crash anymore when changing `<=` to `<` See https://ideone.com/J9b8ar

Comment: `gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406` crashes with Segmentation fault for the code on this link

Comment: @Ruan - Then it is likely a memory allocation problem. You could reduce the input values in order to reduce memory requirements. However, it's probably just better to reconsider your design as you use much more memory than needed. Still - the `<=` must be a bug

Comment: `<=` is a bug. `<` is correct. I implemented `<` plus @M Oehm solution and now it works